# Why isnt mockito injecting the right response?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, testng, mockito

I'm trying to use mockito in the following manner.

Here's a part of  main class `IClient`.

```
public LoginResponse doLogin() {

        WebTarget target = buildTarget();

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> authHeaders = prepareHeaders();
        Builder buildRequest = buildRequest(authHeaders,target); 
        Response loginRsp = buildRequest
                .post(Entity.entity(" Valid JSON string",
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
        if(loginRsp == null)
            LOGGER.error("Response was null");// Response is always returned as null.
```

Here's my test code

```
@Test
public void testdoLoginPass(){
        Response response = Response.ok().build();
        WebTarget webTarget = inner.buildTarget();
        Builder buildRequest = inner.buildRequest( getMockHeaders(),webTarget);

        when(buildRequest.post(Entity.entity(anyString(),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))).thenReturn(response);
      Assert.assertNotNull(inner.doLogin());

}
```

I cant seem to figure out why the response is always null. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

The `inner` is anonmyous inner class  object provides corresponding mock values for `buildTarget()` and `buildRequest()`. I'm able to see that the right mock values are generated by debugging. 
Here is the anonymous inner class

```
inner= new IClient(client, propConfig){
            WebTarget buildTarget(){
                WebTarget target= mock(WebTarget.class);
                LOGGER.error("Returning mock");
                return target;

            }
          Builder buildRequest(final MultivaluedMap<String, Object>  Headers,WebTarget target){
              Builder builder = mock(Builder.class);
              LOGGER.error("Returning mock");
              return builder;
          }
        };
```

**EDIT**-- Based on suggestion to use the same instance.

Here is the refractored version .

```
@Test 
    public void testdoIusLoginPass(){


    inner= new IClient(client, propConfig){
        WebTarget buildIUSTarget(){
            WebTarget target= mock(WebTarget.class);
            LOGGER.error("Returning mock");
            return target;

        }
      Builder buildRequest(final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> authHeaders,WebTarget target){
          builder = mock(Builder.class);
          LOGGER.error("HashCode for Builder from inner Relevant method "+ builder.hashCode());
          LOGGER.error("Returning mock");
          return builder;
      }
    };
    Response response = Response.ok().build();
    WebTarget target = innerIUS.buildIUSTarget();
    builder = innerIUS.buildRequest( getMockHeaders(),target);

    when(builder.post(Entity.entity(any(String.class),
           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))).thenReturn(response)
    Assert.assertNotNull(inner.doLogin());
}
```

Within the actual method

```
 public LoginResponse doIusLogin() {
    WebTarget target = buildIUSTarget();

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> authHeaders = prepareIUSHeaders();
     builder = buildRequest(authHeaders,target); 
     LOGGER.error("HashCode for Builder from doLogin "+ builder.hashCode());//identical hash codes
    Response loginRsp = builder
            .post(Entity.entity("Valid JSON String",
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
    if(loginRsp == null)
        LOGGER.error("Response was null");// Still null.
```

Response is still null. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for following up . Can you elaborate what you mean by injection? Isnt the anonymous inner class doing that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the stubbing together with the mocked objects. E.g.

```
final Response response = Response.ok().build();

IClient inner = new IClient(client, propConfig){
  Builder buildRequest(MultivaluedMap<String, Object> Headers, WebTarget target){
    Builder builder = mock(Builder.class);
    when(builder.post(any(Entity.class)).thenReturn(response)
    return builder;
  }
};

assertNotNull(inner.doLogin());
```

Yet there is a small problem - this test does test almost nothing.

Comment: Also to add, you are right. The test does nothing at this point, I was working through it and noticed this oddity . Couldnt proceed without a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your `when` matcher is never used, that's why it is `null`.

Mockito doesn't do deep arguments comparison, so it compares

```
Entity.entity(anyString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
```

with

```
Entity.entity(" Valid JSON string", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
```

using `Entity.equals` and they don't match. You should either write a custom matcher or replace the former expression with `any(Entity.class)`.

**Edit**: Additionally you are using different instances of `Builder` in your test code and tested class. You should refer to the same instance. Inject it to the tested class.

**Edit #2**: You are recreating `Builder` each time you call `inner.buildRequest`. Write `System.out.println(buildRequest.hashCode());` in your test code and your tested class code, and you will see that they are two **different** instances.

Sorry, but I won't be able to provide you the code that is required to fix your issue - at least I don't see much test infrastructure to be able to do so.

However I should say that testing is very complicated without any [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I would suggest you to integrate some framework (Guice or Spring) and start using it, otherwise you testing process may soon become a nightmare.

Comment: So essentially  you mean this right ? `when(buildRequest.post(Entity.entity(any(Entity.class),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))).thenReturn(response);` . However the response continues to be null.

Comment: I mean this: `when(buildRequest.post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(response);`

Comment: I corrected your suggestion( to include the right brace )  `when(buildRequest.post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(response)` . Response is still null :(

Comment: Does `Entity.entity` method return instance of `Entity.class`?

Comment: I think String . Here's what eclipse tells me `<String> Entity<String> javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(String entity, String mediaType`

Comment: And  here's the regular entity `javax.ws.rs.client.Entity`

Comment: per your edit. Can you please explain how I can inject the builder. I believe the inner class is doing that already?

Answer (score 0):

You should define behavior for moked object.
For example:

```
when(mockedList.get(anyInt())).thenReturn("element");
```

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Comment: This is hardly relevant to the problem. The mocked behavior is defined in the inner anonymous class.